# Unset `show notes on second screen'

Tags: beamer

I use a `slides.sty` package provided by the University which defines lots of things, such as logos, fonts, colors, Beamer styles and other stuff.

Among these settings, it also sets `show notes on second screen`.

How can I *unset* this option? Is there something like `\UNsetbeameroption{show notes on second screen}`, `\setbeameroption{DON'T show notes on second screen}`, or `\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen=NONE}`?

No luck looking for it in Beamer documentation.

I also don't want to have my own version of the file, since updates will be difficult to handle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could change the `pgfpages` layout back to something akin the normal one like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\pgfpagesuselayout{resize to}[physical paper height=\paperheight,physical paper width=\paperwidth]

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    efg
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```

Or you could redefine the `show notes on second screen` option to do nothing before you load your `.sty` file:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\defbeameroption{show notes on second screen}[right]{}

\setbeameroption{show notes on second screen}

\begin{document}
    
\begin{frame}
    abc
\end{frame} 

\begin{frame}
    efg
\end{frame} 
    
\end{document}
```